# auto scale spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, autoscaling

I have a spark streaming job running on a cluster. Spark job pulls messages from Kafka and do the required processing before dumping the processed data to database. I have sized my cluster as per the current load. But this load requirement may go up/down in the future. 
I want to know the techniques to facilitate this auto scaling without restarting the job. Scaling becomes more complicated if kakfa is being used (as in my case) as I won't like the partitions to be moved around in stateful streaming. Currently the cluster is completely in house but I won't mind migrating to cloud if that assists the scaling use case.

Comment: Check out Qubole, a managed big data platform whose USP is workload-aware autoscaling of clusters. It seems to fit your use case exactly. Check out the docs [here](http://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/spark/autoscale-spark.html) (disclaimer: I work at Qubole)

Answer (score 1):

it is not an answer. Just some notes

1. "in stateful streaming". What did you mean by that? All state in spark is distributed. And you should not rely on local system, as if some task failed, it can be send to any other executor.
2. do you speak about increasing size of cluster or resources dedicated for your spark job in cluster?

   If the first one, you need to monitor each node (memory, cpu) and when it's time (hit some threshold) add more nodes.

   If the second one: we didn't find nice solution. Spark provides 'autoscaling' feature, however it doesn't work properly with kafka streaming.

Comment: I am using MapWithState to manange state and that is why I said "in stateful streaming". Spark ensures that the messages with the same key are routed to the same node. I am not worried about adding more resources on the same machine. If I add one more node then kafka partitions reassignment may happen among the nodes although mapWithstate will still ensure that a new message is routed to the node where the last message with same key was routed.